# Create custom list in sharepoint 2007 using JQuery

Tags: jquery, splist

I need to create a custom list in Sharepoint 2007 using JQuery (only!). I'm using Sharepoint 2007. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Only jQuery? No JavaScript allowed?

Comment: Yes only Jquery as javascript won't work in sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SPServices wraps the `Lists` web service:

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists

Which includes `AddList`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist.aspx

Once the list is created, you would use `UpdateList` to add fields or modify other properties:

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateList&referringTitle=Lists

Comment: This is what I needed. Can I edit the column/field name using Updatelist property???  If yes please provide me example.

Comment: did you try giving your own display name in updateList command?

Comment: Giving display name works just fine:)

Comment: Can we create the list based on list template using same method?