# Create custom list in sharepoint with a list template using JQuery

Tags: jquery, splist, list-template

I need to create a custom list in Sharepoint 2007 using JQuery (only!) using a custom **list template**. I'm using Sharepoint 2007. Is there any way to do it?
I already know to create the list and update columns as said at [this Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166821/create-custom-list-in-sharepoint-2007-using-jquery)

Comment: Everything you need is already given to you in the previous question. To create a list using the **Custom List** template, you use the `AddList` function and give it the Custom List template ID (**100**) as a parameter.

Comment: I need to use other **List templates** that was taked from the previously existing list. Not the **Custom List** template that sharepoint provides.